# Discrete Structures $a \pmod 6 = 3$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to prove something by contradiction, However I need to know what $a$ is from the following question.

$a \pmod 6 = 3$
I'm not sure how to figure this out, Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: this means that $a= 6k+3$, where $k$ is a an integer.

Comment: @hachem, hmm, would you know how to prove by contradiction that if          a mod 6 = 3 than a mod 3 Does not = 2?

Comment: @JonRoy $a\bmod 6=3\iff a=6k+3$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$. Then also $a=3(2k+1)$, so $a\bmod 3=0\neq 2$.

Comment: @user236182 So if i was to prove that by contradiction, i could do something like 3(2k+1) mod 3 ≠2?

Comment: @JonRoy If you're specifically asked to prove it by contradiction, then let $a\bmod 3=2$. Then $a=3m+2$ for some $m\in\Bbb Z$. But also $a=3(2k+1)$ (as I showed before), so $3m+2=3(2k+1)$, so $2=3(2k+1-m)$, contradiction, because $2$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Comment: @user236182 Your pretty smart dude. Thanks! I actually understand how to do it now, Thanks man.

Comment: By def. $6 \mid a-3$.